# Delay between Serial Port Open and it Reading input

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have a scale that is attached to a serial port via USB (but I've used Direct serial as well and experienced this problem)
I start my application and call `SerialPort.Open` and it opens fine, according to the call...However, when I push print on the attached scale, I don't get anything in to my queue i set up. Then, after about 20-30 seconds, i am able to push print and everything prints fine.
To add to the confusion, I can open and print to PuTTy at any time, through the same port.
So obviously there's something missing in my code. Here the Output queue with the observer which is set up upon program open:

```
public class Scan_Output_Queue<T> : AFGObservableAFGObserver<T,T>, IEnumerable<T>
{
    private ConcurrentQueue<T> _Queue;

    public Scan_Output_Queue()
    {
        _Queue = new ConcurrentQueue<T>();
    }

    public T Dequeue()
    {
        T item = default(T);
        _Queue.TryDequeue(out item);
        return item;
    }
    public void reinsert(T item)
    {
        Queue<T> queueCopy = new Queue<T>(_Queue.ToArray());
        T junk = default(T);
        foreach (T weight in queueCopy)
        {
            _Queue.TryDequeue(out junk);
        }
        _Queue.Enqueue(item);
        foreach (T weight in queueCopy)
        {
            _Queue.Enqueue(weight);
        }
        base.redraw_Send();
    }
    public void Enqueue(T Item)
    {
        _Queue.Enqueue(Item);
    }

    public T Peek()
    {
        T item = default(T);
        _Queue.TryPeek(out item);
        return item;
    }

    protected override T Receive(T value)
    {
        Enqueue(value);
        return value;
    }



    IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _Queue.GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _Queue.GetEnumerator();
    }


}
```

I place breakpoints in here, but nothing 'magical' happens at the 20-30 second mark. I'm just able to push the print button and it fills the queue.

Here is the requested Scale Reader code. This continuously cycles trying to open the port for that 20-30 seconds:

```
Public Class Scale_Reader

    Public Property Setting_Port As String
    Public Property Setting_Baud As Integer
    Public Property Setting_Parity As System.IO.Ports.Parity
    Public Property Setting_DataBits As Integer
    Public Property Setting_StopBits As Integer
    Public Property Setting_Suffix As String

    Public Property LineSeperator As String = vbCrLf
    Public Property LineSeperator As String = Setting_Suffix


    Public Sub New(ByVal sPort As String, ByVal sBaud As Integer, ByVal sPari_Str As String, ByVal sDataBits As Integer, ByVal sStopBits As Integer, sSuffix As String)
        Setting_Port = sPort
        Setting_Baud = sBaud


        Select Case sPari_Str
            Case "e"
                Setting_Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.Even
            Case "m"
                Setting_Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.Mark
            Case "n"
                Setting_Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.None
            Case "o"
                Setting_Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.Odd
            Case "s"
                Setting_Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.Space
        End Select

        Setting_DataBits = sDataBits
        Setting_StopBits = sStopBits

        If sSuffix.ToUpper() = "CR" Then
            LineSeperator = vbCr
        Else If sSuffix.ToUpper() = "CRLF" Then
            LineSeperator = vbCrLf
        Else
            LineSeperator = ""
        End If

    End Sub



    Public Property PrintString As String

    Public Property ValidExpressions As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
    Public Property InvalidExpressions As List(Of Scale_InvalidExpression) = New List(Of Scale_InvalidExpression)

    Protected Sub Add_ValidExpression(ByVal Expression As String)
        ValidExpressions.Add(Expression)
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Add_InvalidExpression(ByVal Expression As String, ByVal ErrorMessage As String)
        Dim I As Scale_InvalidExpression = New Scale_InvalidExpression()
        I.Expression = Expression
        I.ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage

        InvalidExpressions.Add(I)
    End Sub

    Public Function ReadWeight(Optional GetMode As Integer = 1) As Scale_ReadResults

        Dim Results As Scale_ReadResults = Nothing

        For i As Integer = 1 To 3

            Results = ReadWeightPrivate(GetMode)

            If Results.Valid OrElse Results.ErrorMessage <> "" Then
                Exit For
            End If

        Next

        Return Results

    End Function


    Public Property Cancel_ConstantRead As Boolean = False

    Public Sub ReadWeightConstant(WeightRead As Action(Of Decimal))

        Using Cons_ComPort As SerialPort = New SerialPort()


            Dim ReturnWeight As Decimal = 0
            Dim data As String = ""
            Cancel_ConstantRead = False

            While Not Cons_ComPort.IsOpen 
                    InitializeComPort(Cons_ComPort)
            End While

            While Not Cancel_ConstantRead

                If Not Cons_ComPort.IsOpen Then
                    InitializeComPort(Cons_ComPort)
                End If

                Try
                    While Cons_ComPort.BytesToRead > 0
                        Dim TempData As String = Cons_ComPort.ReadExisting()
                        data += TempData
                        Threading.Thread.Sleep(10)
                    End While
                Catch ex As Exception
                     'InitializeComPort(Cons_ComPort)
                End Try



                'Find whole lines

                Dim Pos As Integer = data.IndexOf(LineSeperator)
                'Dim Pos As Integer = data.IndexOf(vbCr)

                While Pos > -1

                    Dim Line As String = data.Substring(0, Pos)

                    ReturnWeight = TestValidExpressions(Line)

                    If ReturnWeight <> 0 Then
                        'Results.Valid = True
                        'Results.ErrorMessage = ""
                        'Results.Weight = ReturnWeight
                        'Results.RawData = data
                        WeightRead.Invoke(ReturnWeight)
                    End If
                    data = data.Substring(Pos + LineSeperator.Length)
                    'data = data.Substring(Pos + 1)
                    Pos = data.IndexOf(vbCr)

                End While

                Threading.Thread.Sleep(10)
            End While

            If Cons_ComPort.IsOpen Then
                GC.ReRegisterForFinalize(Cons_ComPort.BaseStream)
                Cons_ComPort.Close()
                GC.ReRegisterForFinalize(Cons_ComPort)
            End If

        End Using

    End Sub


    Private Function ReadWeightPrivate(GetMode As Integer) As Scale_ReadResults


        Dim Results As Scale_ReadResults = New Scale_ReadResults()

        Dim ReturnWeight As Decimal = 0
        Dim Attempts As Integer = 20


        Using ComPort As SerialPort = New SerialPort()

            Try
                InitializeComPort(ComPort)
            Catch
                Dim ErrorMessage As String = "Invalid Comm Settings."
                Results.ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage
                Return Results
            End Try

            ComPort.ReadExisting()

            If GetMode = 1 Then
                ComPort.Write(PrintString)
                Attempts = 100
            End If

            Dim NumTries As Integer = 0
            Dim data As String = ""


            While NumTries < Attempts


                While ComPort.BytesToRead > 0
                    data += ComPort.ReadExisting.Replace(Chr(10), " ").Replace(Chr(13), " ")

                End While

                ReturnWeight = TestValidExpressions(data)

                If ReturnWeight <> 0 Then
                    Results.Valid = True
                    Results.ErrorMessage = ""
                    Results.Weight = ReturnWeight
                    Results.RawData = data
                    Exit While
                End If

                Dim ErrorMessage As String = TestInValidExpressions(data)
                If GetMode = 1 AndAlso ErrorMessage.Length > 0 Then
                    Results.Valid = False
                    Results.ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage
                    Results.Weight = 0
                    Results.RawData = data
                    Exit While
                End If

                Threading.Thread.Sleep(10)
                NumTries += 1

                Results.RawData = data

            End While

            ComPort.Close()
        End Using

        Return Results

    End Function


    Private Function TestValidExpressions(ByVal Data As String) As Decimal
        For Each ValidExpression As String In ValidExpressions
            Dim R As New Regex(ValidExpression)
            Dim M As Match = R.Match(Data)
            If M.Success Then
                Dim sWeight = M.Groups("Weight").Value
                Return Val(sWeight)
            End If
        Next
        Return 0
    End Function

    Private Function TestInValidExpressions(ByVal Data As String) As String
        For Each ValidItem As Scale_InvalidExpression In InvalidExpressions
            Dim R As New Regex(ValidItem.Expression)
            Dim M As Match = R.Match(Data)
            If M.Success Then
                Return ValidItem.ErrorMessage
            End If
        Next
        Return ""
    End Function
    Private Sub InitializeComPort(ByRef ComPort As SerialPort)

        ComPort.PortName = Setting_Port
        ComPort.BaudRate = Setting_Baud
        ComPort.Parity = Setting_Parity
        ComPort.StopBits = Setting_StopBits 
        ComPort.DataBits = Setting_DataBits
        ComPort.Handshake = Handshake.None
        Try
            GC.SuppressFinalize(ComPort)
            ComPort.Open()
            GC.SuppressFinalize(ComPort.BaseStream)
        Catch ex As Exception
            '    MessageWindow.Show("COM Port Error", "The COM Port cannot be opened, please check connection", MessageWindow.ButtonStyle.Ok, MessageWindow.IconStyle.Error)

        End Try

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Seeing your code for the Serial port would be much more useful than your queue class.

Comment: I think you would do best re-tagging this as a visual basic coding issue - it is most likely the problem is somewhere in the class to handle the Serial Port, there appears to be no use of the C# class in the VB class. Also I cannot see I am not sure why you would be constantly creating/deleting new Serial Port objects & opening/closing them - this may be part of the reason why you cannot get the data quickly. I would have expected just one Serial Port object to be created & opened.